# SharePoint components location

Tags: windows, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, dynamics-crm

I'm struggling to find location of SharePoint components installed on server.

In my case I'm interested in SharePoint List component for MS Dynamics CRM. The URL clearly says it should be following file and folder `.../crmgrid/crmgridpage.aspx...`, but on server there is no such items.

Where SharePoint components is hidden?

I would appreciate any clue! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static SharePoint pages are stored in the Layouts folder in the SharePoint hive, typically `Program Files\Common files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14` for SharePoint 2010.

Any customized pages are not stored on the web server, but rather in the underlying SQL content databases. If the web pages are represented as files contained within document libraries in SharePoint, you can access them via the UNC path to the libraries (such as `\\site.com\site\subsite\library\myfile.aspx`).

They can also be accessed via SharePoint's [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx) and SharePoint's more traditional [web services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814(v=office.14).aspx).

**Note**: you are not permitted to query the underlying SharePoint database directly or your environment will cease to be supported (and the underlying database has a really bizarre schema anyway).